# I'm getting an import error, does anyone know the solution?

Tags: python, import

hi I'm getting an import error, does anyone know the solution?

ImportError: Bindings generation error. Submodule name should always start with
a parent module name. Parent name: cv2.cv2. Submodule name: cv2

Comment: and how did you do that? please review [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This should do cv2.Submodule  no whitespace.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using opencv-python version 4.6.0.66, try to downgrade to 4.5.5.64 version, on Pycharm you can do that by go to `File`->`Setting`->`Python Interpreter`-> Double-click on `opencv-python` version->check the `specify version` box, then choose older version.

Downgrade opencv also makes the auto-completion works again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Do you know why?

Comment: Anyone knows why it happens?

Comment: pip uninstall opencv-python &&  pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug here that seems to be what you are seeing:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/676