# I installed the openCV library but it cannot be used, how can I fix the problem

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I installed the openCV library but it cannot be used (by pycharm).

What I tried to do:

1. Install the library using `pip install opencv-python`
2. Read the library using `import cv2`, `import cv2 as cv2` - when i write cv. it doesn't show me the available functions and writes me a note

[image]

3. Calling the library using `from cv2 import cv2` it worked but you can't use it

> ImportError: Bindings generation error. Submodule name should always
> start with a parent module name. Parent name: cv2.cv2. Submodule name:
> cv2

Maybe you can help me

Comment: can you share the list of installed "Python Packages" from Pycharm.

Comment: Similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72583781/im-getting-an-import-error-does-anyone-know-the-solution

Comment: Yes, I changed from 4.6.0.66 to 4.5.5.64 and it works :)
Can you please explain to me why it doesn't work in the new version? Are there differences between the versions?

Comment: how about `from cv2 import VideoCapture`, then use `VideoCapture("Mouse.avi")` directly

Comment: After I changed the version of the library it works as usual. I saw a lot of videos on YouTube that simply did import cv2 so I didn't understand why it didn't work for me.

Comment: you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72583781/im-getting-an-import-error-does-anyone-know-the-solution

Comment: even `PyCharm` may have some mistakes in code and some elements may not work in some situations

Comment: Upgrade new version of PyCharrm.

Comment: import cv2 as cv2 to import cv2 as cv

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version of the library and everything worked out.
If you are using opencv-python version 4.6.0.66, try to downgrade to 4.5.5.64 version, you can do that by go to File->Setting->Python Interpreter-> Double-click on opencv-python version->check the specify version box, then choose older version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).